# Append to array from mongodb query result and update database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am developing an express webapp that has a friends list feature, the list is an array that is part of the user record in the database. What I am trying to do is to set up a route that adds the user from the route parameter to the logged in user's friends list array and updates the database.

My approach is to acquire the friends list document via collection.find() query (which works), modify it via javascript and update the database in a callback function.

The modifying part is what causes me problems, since the mongodb queries don't return json, but mongodb query objects. I don't know how to parse them. How can I get only the values to edit from that document?

```
router.get('/users/:specifiedUser/addfriend', function(req, res){

var currentUser = req.user.username;
var specifiedUser = req.params.specifiedUser;

var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('usercollection');

var friendsList = [];
collection.find({ username : currentUser },{ friendsList : 1 }, function (err, result){

  //TODO: convert result values to friendsList array, append specifiedUser to the array that is then updated in the callback



  collection.update({username : currentUser },{friendsList : friendsList }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // return error if it fails
      console.log(err.message);
      return res.render('index', { error : err.message });

    };
  });
  if (err) {
  // return error if it fails
    console.log(err.message);
    return res.render('index', { error : err.message });

  };

});
});
```

Comment: how about tojson(MongoObject)? But if I understand your problem correctly maybe you should consider using $addToSet and $pull operators

Comment: Assuming you are using the [native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/): Collection.find returns a cursor. You have to iterate over the cursor to get the documents. If you are sure, that the amount of data returned is "small" then you can use Collection.find().toArray() to get an array of documents instead of the cursor.

Comment: Generally it's worth to think about using `collection.update` with one of the update operators `$push` or `$addToSet` directly to add the new friend to the list instead of doing read-modify-write at client site. It's more effective and especially atomic.

Comment: I am using monk (https://automattic.github.io/monk/) api in my express app. can I use the native drivers/methods here? if so, could I use toArray() despite i am using a callback in the find call?

Comment: monk [invokes the callback of collection.find with the array of documents](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/blob/master/lib/collection.js#L373) already if no option that changes this (`stream`, `rawCursor`) is provided. So the problem seems why this is not true in your application? Possibly you access the underlying native driver directly by accident? How is the `db` object attached to the `req` created?

Comment: something seems to be wrong with my outer query. when i console.log(result) in it the result is the whole user object (though in square brackets, so i guess it is an array, as you said) instead of just the friendslist key and object.

Comment: MongoDB returns complete/outer documents by `Collection.find`. The projection `{friendsList: 1}` causes that only the `_id` and `friendsList` properties are contained in the result documents - but not that the `friendsList` array is magically extracted from the document. The array you are interested in should be `result[0].friendsList`. But think about the application of `$push` or `$addToSet` update operators as mentioned above.

Comment: If you insist an doing client site read-modify-write of the `friendsList` then you have to `collection.update({username: currentUser}, {$set: {friendsList: friendsList}} ...` otherwise you would replace your entire user document by `{friendsList: friendsList}`

Comment: not sure i fully grasp it yet. you mean is that the result document of the method would normally only return the _id and friendslist properties, but since i access it from within the callback function it coains all the user data (including password etc) because it is all in the logged result.

on another note, the db access is coded serverside since it happens in a route, the client only issues a http get request. or is that not what you mean?

Comment: I mean `collection.find({username: currentUser}, {friendsList: 1})` returns an array of user objects - not an array of friends from the `friendsList`. The only effect of the projection `{friendsList: 1}` is that all properties except `friendsList` and `_id` are omitted from the returned user documents. **But now I see** the projection `{friendsList: 1}` is wrong as 2nd parameter to find. Monk expects an options object there. That's why all user properties are returned. With the native driver the projection is provided by Cursor.project. Don't know how monk handles this.

Comment: thank you, I got it now (at least the outer query). reading the documentation actually helps, who would've thought. In my defense the monk doc is intimidatingly minimal and the queries I had seen in examples were equivalent to mongodb ones. `collection.find({ username : currentUser }, 'friendsList' , function (err, result){...` is the right syntax

Comment: `collection.find({username: currentUser}, {friendsList: 1})` is the signature of the Mongo Shell if `{friendsList: 1}` is intended to be a projection. I was confused about the differences between the [Mongo Native Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), Mongo Shell and Monk. I don't know monk - especially how to provide a projection there. But with or without projection: MongoDB queries return basically the documents from the collection - not nested documents - in your case the user documents (an array of them).